# in 2000 UPS shipped or was shipping one milons of letters a day?

Tags: verbs

what's the correct verb form of this sentence?

> in 2000 UPS shipped or was shipping one million letters a day?

Answer (score 2):

Both are grammatical, but they would typically appear in different contexts.

To talk about the shipping:
"In 2000 UPS shipped one million letters a day"

To indicate that the shipping was ongoing when something else happened:
"In 2000 UPS was shipping one million letters a day when X happened."

Comment: Thank you sooo much Mary